# Pushing existing folders from a server to a project in Gitlab

Tags: git, server, gitlab, git-remote

SO I have a server that is live and it has no git repo in it.  There are however, several files and folders that I would like to push over to a created group project in Gitlab.

I have created a project in Gitlab, 
I have init git in the project files,
I have added the remote branch from gitlab on the server (so when I do git remote -v I see a push and fetch remote branches)

I do however, running into issues when I try to push those files over to the server.  It keeps asking me for a password.  has anyone ran into this?

Comment: Hi, make sure the "remote -v" command gives you the ssh URL of remote; it should start with "ssh://...." and I hope you already added your public key in GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

So after much research I found out that when creating a project in Gitlab you have to to go to settings, and deploy an app key.  This is different than adding your ssh key to your profile, when in a group it needs to be added differently.  once this is done, You should be able to get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up SSH keys.... see docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh

Comment: Thank Joel, I did have a set of SSH keys, what I learned is that this part is different when setting up a repo when a project is in a group.  I posted my answer below.